# Getting unexpected token error when generating build with react-monaco-editor

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor

Getting following error while executing **`npm run build`**:

```
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin ../../node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist ../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-1!../../node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/keybindingLabel/keybindingLabel.css:
2 modules
Child vs/language/typescript/tsWorker:
 1 asset
  [17] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
  [40] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 596 bytes {0} [built]
    + 40 hidden modules

ERROR in ts.worker.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (_isWindows) [ts.worker.js:78,4]
```

**webpack config:**

https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/files/6173508/webpack.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by upgrading the webpack to version 4 from version 3.
This requires upgradation of multiple plugins also, since many of them deprecated and added internally to webpack configuration